# Unable to read value from an edit box in a Tabbed Panel on an xpage

Tags: javascript, xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, xpages-ssjs

I am developing a custom full-text search on an xpage. I have an edit box where the user will enter their search criteria and a search button that builds a custom search string and assigns it to a viewScope variable which is then picked up by a View Panel's search property. This works fine when the edit box and search button are directly on the xpage.

The problem is that the edit box and search button need to be placed on one of the tabs of a Tabbed Panel.  When I place them on the Tabbed Panel I am unable to read values from the edit box, and I can't see why!

The code on the search button to read the value from the edit box is:

```
var component = getComponent('searchString');
var searchCriteria = component.getValue();
```

`component` contains an object (I checked with `_dump(component)`) but `searchCriteria` is always null when the edit box and button are in the Tabbed Panel.

Any suggestions as to why this is would be gratefully received.

Comment: Try getSubmittedValue() but even better: go straight to the data source of searchCriteria

Comment: even better, to use this xsnippets, you don't have to worry about when to use which method to get the value, https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=getcomponentvalue

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten - I did try `getSubmittedValue` but that is null too when the field is in the Tabbed Panel.  What do you mean by going straight to the data source of searchCriteria?  (Excuse my ignorance - although I have been using Notes for nearly 20 years I haven't done much with xpages!)  Thanks for taking the time to reply btw.

Comment: Could you paste the button code? 
Is checked the option "No update" or  "partial execution" of a different panel?

Answer (score 1):

Try binding the input text to a viewScope variable:

```
<xp:inputText id="tururu" value="#{viewScope.searchText}" />
```

Then you can access the value is ssjs just with:

```
var searchCriteria = viewScope.searchText;
```